# Can Celery tasks survive restart?

Tags: celery

I need to build a system which handles two types of tasks. One type can create more tasks of itself or of the other type. There will be very few workers (2-3) and only one host. The most important requirement is that the system should handle restarts gracefully: i.e. on restart, tasks that were in progress should start from scratch and the workers should pick up tasks which were queued prior to restart.
Looking at Celery it appears to be suitable for this use case. However, I have a couple of questions:

1) Is Celery able to handle restarts of the whole system as described? (Celery + workers + broker, everything restarts, complete power failure).

2) What is the best broker to use for this scenario? I would prefer SQLAlchemy + SQLite as it is more "self contained", but if RabbitMQ is the right choice, given the requirement to handle full restarts gracefully, then I can go with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) Is Celery able to handle restarts of the whole system as described? (Celery + workers + broker, everything restarts, complete power failure).

> Yes, When you create your own queue on RabbitMQ  ( **Persistent
>   queue** ) even after the restart of your server the task will be
>   resumed and will be carried out by Celery.

2) What is the best broker to use for this scenario? I would prefer SQLAlchemy + SQLite as it is more "self contained", but if RabbitMQ is the right choice, given the requirement to handle full restarts gracefully, then I can go with it.

> USe RabbitMQ. we are using RabbitMQ + Celery in production. So i would
>   suggest you to use RabbitMQ as a broker.

[Celery + RabbitMQ Best Practice](https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/)

[Message Reliability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html)

Notes :

1. Use more Queues (ie. not just the default one)
2. Use priority workers
3. Use Celery's error handling mechanisms

Comment: Thanks. I will build it with Celery + RabbitMQ with durable queue and durable exchange.

Comment: Hi @StefanD sure. If you need more help do let me know

Comment: @Backtrack I have a task where it does some process on a machine restarts that machine. Will Rabbit MQ be able to identify the task as complete and will the Celery task support this? Where it will come back to see that it has only executed partial of the task?

Comment: upvoted :) wouldnt sqlite have problems if celery workers try to access it in a multiprocess/thread setting?